# Cannot maintain a connection to a Battlefield 4 Multiplayer Match on Playstation 4

Tags: technical-issues, battlefield-4, ps4

I've had my PS 4 and Battlefield 4 (BF4) for about four weeks now; for the first three weeks, it had been rock solid, never a glitch, not a single dropped connection.  For the last week (and more, now), I have been unable to play for more than a couple of minutes before my connection to the server gets dropped.  Playing a full match is nearly impossible.  Sometimes, I can't connect at all.

1. I have tried the PSN fix - unplug my router and shut off the PS4 for three minutes then try again - which didn't help.
2. I have tried assigning a static IP to the PS4 and port forwarding more ports than you can shake a stick at*, which also did not help.
3. Per the @AskPlaystation twitter account, I tried booting to safe mode and rebuilding the database - no changes noted.
4. Most recently, I did a full system restore and reinstall of BF4, also with no changes noted.
5. I have tried yelling obcenities in the mic on the controller - no help.

The only correlation I can find is the new patch that was pushed on September 2nd - that is right around when I first noticed connectivity issues.  I'm not saying the patch is the problem, but it is the only change to the system that correlates to the decreased performance.

---

*ports I have forwarded: 
     TCP: 80, 443, 465, 983, 1935, 3478-3480, 5223, 10071-10080 
     UDP: 88, 3658, 3659, 3478-3479
    BOTH: 80, 3074, 3478-3480, 10070

Comment: Does the connectivity occur with other games?

Comment: I have no other online games.

Comment: You don't need to forward ports.  I would guess this is just due to a flaky Internet connection - try calling your ISP's tech support.

Comment: I've been playing BF4 on PS4 without issues before and after the September 2 patch. Try running [Pingtest](http://www.pingtest.net/) with servers in various locations around the world to see if you've got an unstable connection and, if so, which regions have the worst stability (you can filter them out in the server browser). If you're not already using a wired connection, try that if possible (and compare Pingtest results).

Comment: Can you check whether [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) is still enabled on your router?

Comment: @SilverlightFox Yep, I'll do so and update my post with that information.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - CenturyLink tech support?  Isn't that an oxymoron?  LOL... How would I diagnose my connection as being flaky?  I stream HD movies and whatnot (which admittedly may disguise issues by buffering) from Amazon and Netflix without difficulty.